# How can I retrieve multiple objects by key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was just looking in the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html) but couldn't find anything.

So my web app has a structure that's similar to the one in this site.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say my app has only `questions` which are catalogued by `tags`. As suggested in the docs, we store our data with a flat, non-normalized structure (E.g.

```
{
  "questions": {
    ...
  },
  "tags": { 
    "tag1": { 
      "name": "Tag1", 
      "questions": { "0": true, "1": true } 
    }, 
    "tag2": {
      "name": "Tag2",
      "questions": { "2": true, "3": true }
    }
  }
}
```

), rather than a normalized structure without data replication like:

```
{ 
  "questions": { 
    "0": { "title": ..., "tag": ... },
    "1": { "title": ..., "tag": ... },  
   }
}
```

One of the advantages of using the first structure is that I can search for questions that have a certain tag without downloading all the data of all of the questions first: querying for `/tags/tag1/questions`, will return all the object with all of the question's keys. Now, I can query for the questions, but how do I do that?

I don't want to make ten requests for every question, it seems a waste of time and performance, but I couldn't find a way to make Firebase filter by multiple keys. It seems I can only give Firebase one input at a time. I think (and I hope) I am missing something here. What is it?

If I really can't do this, how do I search by tags here?

Comment: OR queries are currently not supported in Firebase. This has been asked before, so I'll probably mark this as a duplicate of one of those. In general if you need to do multiple queries, consider adding an index to prevent. So in this case: **also** store the questions on their own. Data duplication is pretty common in NoSQL databases.

Comment: I just realized that you're not actually doing multiple **queries**, just accessing multiple child nodes. Direct access to a node is a very efficient operation, so I wouldn't prematurely optimize it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "OR queries aren't supported" Are AND queries supported? Because then I could just retrieve questions that have
`tag1 in q.tags AND tag2 in q.tags AND tag3 IN q.tags ...` and so on. Maybe Firebase, isn't gonna do it for this app thought. It's just a shame because it's so simple!

Comment: No, AND queries are also not directly supported. But sometimes you can emulate them by combining properties. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase